# VSTO Programmatically adding a new worksheet based on an existing one

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

I currently have a [C# Workbook-level Office 2007 Addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcfbd2sk.aspx) that has a [Worksheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet(VS.80).aspx) added at design-time where I have added methods and properties to the [Worksheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet(VS.80).aspx) derived class.

I want to be able to programatically make a new worksheet that **clones**, **inherits** or otherwise possesses the methods and event handlers of this **existing Worksheet class** automatically.

If this can be achieved then please could someone outline how this could be achieved? C# demo code would be preferably although any .NET code would be acceptable.

Thank-you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now come to the conclusion that it's not actually feasible to duplicate these classes in their existing state as I was looking for.

According to the [Host Items and Host Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z4e3456.aspx): in Document Level Addins, Host Items cannot be created programmatically but only at design time. This is reinforced in the further [explanation of the programmatic limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178779.aspx) of Host items and host controls, particularly for document level addins.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think you can do what the OP asked -- duplicate existing worksheet and extend it at runtime. But you can, according to  http://tinyurl.com/bqej98z, create new worksheets and get the host items created.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, good question, and I'll be keeping an eye on what comes up on here.

A few months ago, I had a similar problem, and needed to create code and events on dynamically created sheets. To be able to do that, however, I ended up creating VBA script objects within the sheet.

So the process was:

1. User Clicks button in Excel
2. C# process creates new Sheet
3. C# process creates VBA object on sheet and creates events, etc

```
     oBook = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook;

    oModule = oBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

    string sCode = "sub myVBASub()\r\n"+
            "msgbox("Hello")\r\n"+
            "End Sub\r\n";

    oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
```

Comment: Old Nick: Thanks for sharing that, I hadn't thought of doing it that way, I guess the only problem is that you can't call those events from your C# Add-in can you?

Comment: Possibly.... Though the only interactions I've done is through a menu added to excel 2003, however, this (http://tinyurl.com/yfs665r) implies that you could connect to some controls, as VSTO runs in the same namespace.